# Replace each character in string by float from dictionary and sum all replaced values together

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I want a value of each string in `simsec_0` which is calculated by replacing all the characters with float from dictionary `monoisotopicaa_dict`

```
peptides_report = {'simsec_0': ['CCYYK', 'TTSS']}
monoisotopicaa_dict = {"C":103.00919,"E":129.04259,"Q":128.05858, \
                    "K":128.09496,"M":131.04049,"F":147.06841, \
                    "S":87.03203,"T":101.04768,"W":186.07931,"Y":163.06333}
```

The expected result is something like

```
{'simsec_0':[['CCYYK',660.24], ['TTSS',376.15942]]}
```

So I try to write function `CALC` replacing each string `p_v_each` with float from dictionary

```
def CALC(peptides_report, monoisotopicaa_dict):
    for p_k, p_v in peptides_report.iteritems():
        for p_v_each in p_v:
            for mono_each in monoisotopicaa_dict.keys():
            # May be replace with number and "+"
                # string = p_v_each.replace(mono_each, monoisotopicaa_dict[mono_each])

xxx = CALC(peptides_report, monoisotopicaa_dict)
```

What should I do with the string to get value and able to sum them?

Comment: You don't want to be dealing with strings at all here. You want to use `sum` and lookup the values to add by looking up each character in the dictionary...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use the fact that a string is a collection of characters and extract the values inside `sum` with a comprehension:

```
>>> values = {"C":103.00919,"E":129.04259,"Q":128.05858, \
...                     "K":128.09496,"M":131.04049,"F":147.06841, \
...                     "S":87.03203,"T":101.04768,"W":186.07931,"Y":163.06333}
>>> values
{'Q': 128.05858, 'C': 103.00919, 'E': 129.04259, 'T': 101.04768, 'W': 186.07931, 'F': 147.06841, 'Y': 163.06333, 'K': 128.09496, 'M': 131.04049, 'S': 87.03203}
>>> sum(values[l] for l in 'CCYYK')
660.2400000000001
>>> sum(values[l] for l in 'TTSS')
376.15942
>>> [sum(values[l] for l in word) for word in ['CCYYK', 'TTSS']]
[660.2400000000001, 376.15942]
```

To put the values into the dict:

```
report = {'simsec_0': ['CCYYK', 'TTSS']}

monoisotopicaa = {"C":103.00919,"E":129.04259,"Q":128.05858, \
                  "K":128.09496,"M":131.04049,"F":147.06841, \
                  "S":87.03203,"T":101.04768,"W":186.07931,"Y":163.06333}
def value(word):
    return sum(monoisotopicaa[l] for l in word)

{k:[[w, value(w)] for w in v] for k,v in report.items()}
# {'simsec_0': [['CCYYK', 660.2400000000001], ['TTSS', 376.15942]]}
```

Comment: Or `{k:[[el, sum(d2[ch] for ch in el)] for el in v] for k, v in d1.items()}` as a `dict`-comp...

Comment: Got it, thanks. Do you have any idea how to put the number back as a list `{'simsec_0':[['CCYYK',660.24], ['TTSS',376.15942]]}`?